# angular2 + wijmo5 - Annotation Line

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-directives, devextreme, wijmo5

How can a plot a probability distribution chart in my Angular 2 application.

I tried using the wijmo annotation line. It worked using start and end point coordinates.
I need to plot the line using x-y data coordinate points.

Also tried attachment property with the wj-flex-chart-annotation-line (DataIndex, and DataCoordinate). How I need to specify data points with the attachment option. What is the value needed to provide with the data type point with attachment option?

```
<wj-flex-chart [itemsSource]="data" [chartType]="'Spline'" [bindingX]="'country'">

    <wj-flex-chart-axis [wjProperty]="'axisX'" [title]="titleX" [labels]="false"></wj-flex-chart-axis>
    <wj-flex-chart-axis [wjProperty]="'axisY'" [title]="titleY"></wj-flex-chart-axis>

    <wj-flex-chart-series [binding]="'sales'"></wj-flex-chart-series>

    <wj-flex-chart-annotation-layer>
        <wj-flex-chart-annotation-line [position]="2" [start]="{x: 250, y: 0}" [end]="{x: 250, y: 300}" ></wj-flex-chart-annotation-line>        
        <wj-flex-chart-annotation-line [attachment]="'DataIndex'" [wjProperty]="'axisX'" [pointIndex]="2"></wj-flex-chart-annotation-line>
    </wj-flex-chart-annotation-layer>
</wj-flex-chart>

data = [
  {'country': "US", 'downloads': 3457, 'sales': 1681.374337182966}, 
  {'country': "Germany", 'downloads': 467, 'sales': 5821.869030096296}, 
  {'country': "UK", 'downloads': 12151, 'sales': 2260.865004748749}, 
  {'country': "Japan", 'downloads': 19762, 'sales': 2331.3376444697155}, 
  {'country': "Italy", 'downloads': 13341, 'sales': 6264.880417785565}, 
  {'country': "Greece", 'downloads': 1088, 'sales': 80.409117985476}
];
```

Reference links used are:

[Angular 2 Chart Annotation](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo-wijmo.angular2.chart.annotation.Module.html)

[WjFlexChartAnnotationLine Class](http://205.186.148.117/5/docs/topic/wijmo-wijmo.angular2.chart.annotation.WjFlexChartAnnotationLine.Class.html)

Thank You.

Comment: Please post what code you have tried to plot the chart and any error you are getting. If you don't know where to begin to write the code please google first.

Comment: @iceman I have included the tried code snippet.